# Removing duplicates from a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set

I have a list of tuples, and I want to remove duplicate tuples. Something like this.

```
x = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd'],['aaron','jeng']]
```

I want the output something like this :

```
y = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd']]
```

How can I do that in an easy way? I can write code to do that, but is there any inbuilt function for this?

Edit 1 : As everyone has suggested, I'm sorry to call them tuples. I meant a list of lists. Thank You.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate tuples"? Your example is not even tuple.

Comment: Those are lists, not tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Your x value does not contain a list of tuples, but a list of lists. If it *did* contain a list of tuples:

```
x = [('aaron','jeng'),('sdf','wqd'),('aaron','jeng')]
out = set([i for i in x])
print(list(out))

[('aaron', 'jeng'), ('sdf', 'wqd')]
```

Comment: Why bother with the comprehension? `set(x)` works fine.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Not quite; a set comprehension would be `{i for i in x}`. `set(i for i in x)` is passing a generator expression to `set`.

Comment: list is unhashable @user2357112

Comment: @JacobIRR: You probably tested that with a list of lists, as in the question, rather than a list of tuples, as in your answer.

Comment: @user2357112 `myset =  set( tuple(a) for a in x )`  is not a set comprehension?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Not a set comprehension. `{tuple(a) for a in x}` would be a set comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

That's a list of lists... But no matter, you can use a temporary set to make sure there are no repeats:

```
x = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd'],['aaron','jeng']]

seen = set()  # store here the visited tuples
y = [e for e in x if tuple(e) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(e))]
# [['aaron', 'jeng'], ['sdf', 'wqd']]
```

If you convert your inner lists to tuples upfront it will have a considerably better performance.

If you don't need to preserve the order, then just convert the inner lists to tuples and turn your `x` to a `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy with a list of tuples, you would simply need `set(x)`. Since your list is a list of lists, and not a list of tuples, you can convert them first:

```
set(tuple(i) for i in x)
```

returns:

```
{('aaron', 'jeng'), ('sdf', 'wqd')}
```

Or, if you want to reconvert to a list of lists as you had it:

```
[list(t) for t in (set(tuple(i) for i in x))]
# [['aaron', 'jeng'], ['sdf', 'wqd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have tuples, you have lists inside lists.

```
x = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd'],['aaron','jeng']]

uniques = list (set ( tuple(a) for a in x))
```

Is a generator expression fed into a set thats then fed to a list resulting in

```
[('aaron', 'jeng'), ('sdf', 'wqd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and `any`:

```
x = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd'],['aaron','jeng']]
new_x = [[a, b] for i, [a, b] in enumerate(x) if not any(c == b for _, c in x[:i])]
```

Output:

```
[['aaron', 'jeng'], ['sdf', 'wqd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about converting to a dict , Because dict can have unique keys :

```
x = [['aaron','jeng'],['sdf','wqd'],['aaron','jeng']]

print({tuple(i):i for i in x}.values())
```

output:

```
[['aaron', 'jeng'], ['sdf', 'wqd']]
```